# ACS: Filtering events based on ExtendedProperties

Tags: google-apps-script, google-calendar-api

I'm trying to lists the events  matching the value of a shared ExtendedProperty.
I have validated my parameters using the [API explorer](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events/list?apix=true), but I can't figure out the syntax I'm supposed to use in a Google Apps script.

So far, I've tried

```
Calendar.Events.list(cal_id, {sharedExtendedProperties: {key1: val1}});
```

,

```
Calendar.Events.list(cal_id, {sharedExtendedProperties: `key1=${val1}`});
```

and

```
Calendar.Events.list(cal_id, {extendedProperties: {shared: {key1: val1}}});
```

with no success.

Am I missing something ?

Comment: Does this work for one filter? `sharedExtendedProperties:  \`key1=${val1}\``

Comment: @TheMaster no, it does not, but neither does the "dictionary" way. I'm editing my question to first find out how to match one property.

Comment: try `Calendar.Events.list(cal_id, {extendedProperties:Calendar.newEventExtendedProperties().setShared({'key':'value'})})`

Comment: @TheMaster, no more success with the newEventExtendedProperties. I've finally found my mistake: 'y'≠'ies'

Comment: Glad to know...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I misread the API, the answer is:

```
Calendar.Events.list(cal_id, {sharedExtendedProperty: `key1=${val1}`})
```

Notice the "sharedExtendedPropert>**y**<" (singular, that I missed at first).

For multiple properties, an array is needed:

```
Calendar.Events.list(cal_id, {sharedExtendedProperty:
  [`key1=${val1}`,
   `key2=${val2}`]
})
```